# How can use unicode character in NHibernate HQL + SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, hql

I Use NHibernate 4.X + SQL Server for our ERP and we use HQL with where clause that contains unicode character.

My problem is searching for the unicode string.

For example:

```
 select o.ID, o.Name 
 from MyClass o 
 where o.Name like '%محمدی%'
```

There are many records that match this condition, but HQL does not return any result.

The unicode character 'ی' causes this problem.

Then equivalent SQL has no result:

```
select o.ID, o.Name 
from MyTable o 
where o.Name like '%محمدی%'
```

But this SQL does return the correct results:

```
select o.ID, o.Name 
from MyTable o 
where o.Name like N'%محمدی%'
```

The `N'` before strings in HQL solves this problem.

My question is: how can we configure NHibernate to put `N'` prefix before generated SQL?